# Is there a good design pattern for checking permissions when running a method?

Tags: java, design-patterns, permissions

I'm looking for a design pattern or a approach to tidy up my code. This is in the context of security and checking permissions for a given subject.
Here is a simplified example:

```
public Pizza bakePizza() throws UnauthorizedException{
if (subject.isPermitted("BAKE_PIZZA")){
        return new Pizza();
    } else {
        throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make this a bit more clean because this can get quite messy when I have a lot of different kinds of methods like this.

Comment: Aspects might clean up the code, if aspect oriented programming is an option. Check out Shiro.

Comment: @Sotirios Actually, I am using Shiro and the subject is a Shiro-object :) But for Shiro's annotations to work you have to use AOP and I have absolutely no experience with AOP and this project is not the right for experimenting with new programming styles. This is why I'm looking for another way of doing things :) But thanks for your suggestion anyway!

Comment: You can add a checking code by modifying a class file when the JVM loads it. [Javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) can do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think splitting security constraints and bussines logic by using something like the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) would be a good start.

How about something like this:

```
// an interface defines the operations
public interface PizzaService {
  Pizza bakePizza();
}

// standard implementation that contains the business logic
public class PizzaServiceImpl implements PizzaService {
  @Override
  public Pizza bakePizza() {
    // implementation ..
  }
}

// implementation with security constraints that delegates to the real implementation
public class SecurePizzaService implements PizzaService {
  private PizzaService service;
  public SecurePizzaService(PizzaService service) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  @Override
  public Pizza bakePizza() {
    if (!subject.isPermitted("BAKE_PIZZA")){
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    service.bakePizza()
  }
}

// usage
PizzaService pizzaService = new SecurePizzaService(new PizzaServiceImpl());
...
Pizza pizza = pizzaService.bakePizza();
```

This way you could change security constraints without touching business logic and vice versa.

If you have a lot of situations like this you should have a look at [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) frameworks like [AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/)

Comment: Marked this as the answer because I have to agree that security constraints and business logic has to be separated. I might have to look into AOP some day :)

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to move the check logic into a method that throws and thereby ends the program flow of the calling method early.

```
public Pizza bakePizza() throws UnauthorizedException{
    ensurePermission("BAKE_PIZZA");
    return new Pizza();
}

private void ensurePermission(String permission) throws UnauthorizedException {
    if (!subject.isPermitted(permission))
        throw new UnauthorizedException();
}
```

Comment: And make it a runtime exception (like shiro).

Comment: Depends a bit on your intention of that exception. It's fine to make it a runtime exception if the client of this class can expect that there are no exceptions when using the class in the intended way. If permissions can silently change and the client has to expect that something out of his control goes wrong I'd keep it a checked exception.